# How to implement functions for every page on Angular 10 project

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Hello i am trying to do this in my Angular 10 project

[How to translate in Ionic 5— Internationalization and Localization](https://enappd.com/blog/how-to-translate-in-ionic-internationalization-and-localization/143/?fbclid=IwAR2MzGiNx9MP34falsiwuxKyNT9Ab2kyiwqfy8dmsVOfnd4h42inWZyGiOM)
It works just fine but i want to implement it for every page not just one. I put the code in a service but i dont know how to call it in the page.html

translate.service.ts

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { Globalization } from '@ionic-native/globalization/ngx';
  import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

 @Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
  })
  export class TranslateConfigService {

 public title: string;
 public title_2: string;
 public description: string;
 public name: string;
 public language: string;


  constructor(
    private globalization: Globalization, 
    private _translate: TranslateService,
    ) {
  });
 }

 ngOnInit() {
 }

this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.statusBar.styleDefault();
  this.splashScreen.hide();
});
if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
  setTimeout(() => {
      this.userData.registerFCM();
  }, 4500);
 }
}



 ionViewDidEnter(): void {
   this.getDeviceLanguage()
 }

 _initialiseTranslation(): void {
    this._translate.get('TITLE').subscribe((res: string) => {
    this.title = res;
  });
  this._translate.get('description').subscribe((res: string) => {
  this.description = res;
  });
   this._translate.get('TITLE_2', { value: 'John' }).subscribe((res: string) => {
    this.title_2 = res;
  });
   this._translate.get('data.name', { name_value: 'Marissa Mayer' }).subscribe((res: string) => {
   this.name = res;
  });

 }

  public changeLanguage(): void {
    this._translateLanguage();
  }

  _translateLanguage(): void {
    this._translate.use(this.language);
    this._initialiseTranslation();
  }

  _initTranslate(language) {
   // Set the default language for translation strings, and the current language.
   this._translate.setDefaultLang('en');
    if (language) {
      this.language = language;
    }
    else {
      // Set your language here
      this.language = 'en';
     }
    this._translateLanguage();
   }

  getDeviceLanguage() {
     if (window.Intl && typeof window.Intl === 'object') {
     this._initTranslate(navigator.language)
   }
   else {
     this.globalization.getPreferredLanguage()
      .then(res => {
        this._initTranslate(res.value)
      })
    .catch(e => {console.log(e);});
   }
 }
 }
```

page.html

```
 <ion-item>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="language" [value]="language" (ionChange)="changeLanguage()">
    <ion-select-option value="en">English</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="es">Spanish</ion-select-option>
    <ion-select-option value="fr">French</ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>

<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      Translated by HTTP Loader - From external JSON
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
<ion-card class="ion-padding">
  <ion-card-header>
    Simple
  </ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-content>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ description }}</p>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
<ion-card class="ion-padding">
  <ion-card-header>
    Simple with directive
  </ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-content>
    <h1 translate>TITLE</h1>
    <p [translate]="'description'"></p>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>

<ion-card class="ion-padding">
  <ion-card-header>
    With Params
  </ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-content>
    <h1>{{ title_2 }}</h1>
    <p>{{ description }}</p>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>

<ion-card class="ion-padding">
  <ion-card-header>
    With params, with directive
  </ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-content>
    <h1 [translate]="'TITLE_2'" >TITLE</h1>
    <p [translate]="'description'"></p>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
<ion-card class="ion-padding">
  <ion-card-header>
    With Params, nested JSON data and directive
  </ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-content>
    <h1>{{name}}</h1>
    <h1 translate >data.name</h1>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

i only caled the sevice in page.ts

```
  import { TranslateConfigService } from '../../services/translate/translate.service';
```

Any idea? And what about the globalization module? it is deprecated? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:** To translate for every page, you have to create a service to do it. You may put all the code examples in the service to use it from the entire aplication. A simple way after install ngx-translate and declare the library in the `app.module.ts`. Import the service on each page that you need to translate. Create a file: `translate.service.ts` and put inside:

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

  @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })
  export class TranslateConfigService {

    constructor(public translate: TranslateService) {
      translate.addLangs(['en', 'fr']);
      translate.setDefaultLang('en');

      const browserLang = translate.getBrowserLang();
      translate.use(browserLang.match(/en|fr/) ? browserLang : 'en');
    }
```

There are a Stackblitz [example](https://stackblitz.com/github/ngx-translate/example), and you can have a deep understanding by looking into de library documentation here: [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#usage).

Comment: yes i updated to show you service ts file. I called it on page.ts but i have to put the functions too in page.ts? How will it know how to run the functions in translate.service.ts?

Comment: as far as i understood you want to get the default language from the system and then use ngx-translate. For that put the detection of the language in the app.component and it will be called once you start the app (page does not matter). In the single pages i use the translate pipe. If you have dynamic text that needs to be translated diffrently subscribe to the onLangChanged observable. https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#properties